# How to import fields to columns from an XML file

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd">
<article lang="">
  <para/>
  <para/>
  <informaltable frame="all">
    <tgroup cols="2.4"><tbody><row><entry namest="c1" nameend="c3"><para>Informe No. 08- 1696 </para></entry><entry namest="c4" nameend="c5"><para>Pagina 1 de 1</para></entry></row><row><entry namest="c1" nameend="c3"><para>Apellidos:   COLINA</para></entry><entry namest="c4" nameend="c5"><para>Nombres:   GELA</para></entry></row><row><entry><para>Edad: 50a</para></entry><entry><para>Sexo:  F</para></entry><entry><para>Historia No.: </para></entry><entry><para>Entrada: 15-01-2008</para></entry><entry><para>Salida: 17-01-2008</para></entry></row><row><entry namest="c1" nameend="c3"><para>Remitente:    Dr. Mano Paz</para></entry><entry namest="c4" nameend="c5"><para>Institución: Torre Sur</para></entry></row><row><entry namest="c1" nameend="c5"><para>Origen y Naturaleza del Material:    Orina (muestra A, B y C )</para></entry></row></tbody></tgroup>
  </informaltable>
  <para/>
  <para/>
  <para/>
  <para>INFORME CITOLOGICO</para>
  <para/>
  <para>A.- MACROSCOPICO:   Se recibe envase conteniendo 15 cc de orina, el cual se centrifuga, se extiende en láminas portaobjetos y se colorea para evaluación microscópica.</para>
  <para/>
  <para>        RESULTADO:  FROTIS CITOLOGICO NEGATIVO.        </para>
  <para/>
  <para>B.- MACROSCOPICO:   Se recibe envase conteniendo 14 cc de orina, el cual se centrifuga, se extiende en láminas portaobjetos y se colorea para evaluación microscópica.</para>
  <para/>
  <para>        RESULTADO:  FROTIS CITOLOGICO NEGATIVO.        </para>
  <para/>
  <para>C.- MACROSCOPICO:   Se recibe envase conteniendo 13 cc de orina, el cual se centrifuga, se extiende en láminas portaobjetos y se colorea para evaluación microscópica.</para>
  <para/>
  <para>        RESULTADO:  FROTIS CITOLOGICO NEGATIVO.        </para>
  <para/>
  <para/>
  <para/>
  <para>                                                </para>
  <para/>
</article>
```

I need to import the `<para>` tags that have information in them using either `MYSQL LOAD` or `MYSQL XML` and put the content of each `<para>` in a column SO that for each XML file I import I get 1 row. The end result would look something like this:

```
Column1 - - - Column2 - - - Column3 - - - Column4

1st Para - - -2nd Para - -  3rd Para - -  4th Para
```

And so on for all `<para>` tags. Right now the default behavior if I try to import this file, each `<para>` content will go in a row instead of a column, creating for example 20 rows for the same file (Each information in a row) instead of importing every field on the same row but on different columns. How can I set this up so that they go in each column instead of rows.

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

What I want is for each file to be in a column, instead of a row as shown in the image. Know that this will be done to about 50.000+ files so each XML file should be a row and it's fields a column, instead of each field of that XML becoming a row. Basically, all fields should go in a column and only take one row so that 1 row = 1 XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you already have each `<para>` in a row, so, after loading each file into the `para1` column, you can try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT('"',MID(REPLACE(para1, '.', ''),INSTR(REPLACE(para1, '.', ''),':')+1),'"' ' AS `', LEFT(REPLACE(para1, '.', ''),INSTR(REPLACE(para1, '.', ''),':')-1),'`' SEPARATOR ','), 
  ' FROM `para` LIMIT 0,1')
INTO @qry
FROM `para`;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[Try it in SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0719/1)

OUTPUT:

```
EDAD  |  SEXO  |  HISTORIA NO  |  ENTRADA  |  SALIDA  |  REMITENTE  |  INSTITUCION  | ORIGEN Y NATURALEZA DEL MATERIAL |

  50a |      F |               |15-01-2008 |17-01-2008|             |               |        Orina (muestra A, B y C)  |
```

Comment: Do all of them have the same `<para>` (Edad, Sexo, etc)?

Comment: Why don't you import one file at a time and execute my code to have each file categorized? Sorry, but I can't see the problem of using it for multiple files nor the advantage of doing it the way you say.

Comment: BTW, if you already plan to have a temp table with that data, please post its format in your question so that we can help you using it as a starting point.

Comment: I understand that table as what you where looking for, rather than a starting point you already had. I'm actually asking for the table with all the imported `<para>` in different rows (the one you talk about in `Right now if I try to import this file, each <para> content will go in a row instead of a column.`) That table you don't like is the starting point of my example.

Comment: Sorry, but why can't you execute my code after loading each file? I imagine the load of the files will be iterative by code (not one by one). I just can't see why can't you execute in each iteration my code. The case is that once you have the big table you are asking for, the next step will be something similar to my solution, so why don't you skip a step?

Comment: Please update your code so it is compatible with the table as shown in the image. The table name is "para" and each column is named para followed by a number.

Comment: Why did you delete all your comments?

Comment: Save up space. Comments should not be carried out for so long.